Given positive $a,b,c$, show that $\frac{1}{4a^2-ab+4b^2}+\frac{1}{4b^2-bc+4c^2}+ \frac{1}{4c^2-ca+4a^2}\geq \frac{9}{7(a^2+b^2+c^2)}$
This is question 41 of this inequality exercise sheet, and a solution is provided. However, the author's solution is purposefully cumbersome, showing how complicated brute force solution can get.
Here is the given solution (in short):

Expanding the inequality, we see it is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{cyc}56a^6-28a^5b+128a^4b^2+44a^3b^3+\frac{95}{2}a^4bc+31a^3b^2c-\frac{45}{2}a^2b^2c^2\geq 0
$$
Taking a suitable linear combination of the following inequalities and an application of AM-GM yields the above:
$$
\sum_{cyc}a^6-2a^5b+a^4bc \geq 0 \tag{1}
$$
$$
\sum_{cyc}a^5b-4a^4b^2+3a^3b^3\geq 0  \tag{2}\\
$$
$$
\sum_{cyc}a^4b^2-a^4bc-a^3b^3+2a^3b^2c-a^2b^2c^2\geq 0 \tag{3}\\
$$
$$
\sum_{cyc}a^4bc-2a^3b^2c+a^2b^2c^2\geq 0 \tag{4}
$$

I am looking for a more elegant solution, if possible. I've tried a few obvious thing like Cauhcy-Schwarz/Titu's Lemma:
$$
\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{4a^2-ab+4b^2} \geq \frac{9}{8(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(ab+bc+ca)}=\frac{9}{7(a^2+b^2+c^2)+[(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(ab+bc+ca)]}
$$
But since $a^2+b^2+c^2>ab+bc+ca$, this approach does not work.

Approach Zero search (https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B4a%5E2-ab%2B4b%5E2%7D%24&p=1) led to the following nice solution in the link https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h404795p2258599
